# Maximal subring of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ containing $T_n(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to find a maximal subring $S$ (eventually all maximal subrings) of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries, such that $S$ contains the upper triangular matrix ring $T_n(\mathbb R)$.

Here is what I've tried:

For $M_2(\mathbb R)$, if $S$ properly contains $T_2(\mathbb R)$ then its vector space dimension must be 4 and hence $S=M_2(\mathbb R)$. So $T_2(\mathbb R)$ is itself maximal.

For $M_3(\mathbb R)$, the set $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\ 0&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ 0 &a_{32}&a_{33}\end{bmatrix}: a_{ij}\in\mathbb R\right\}$ is a subring of $M_3(\mathbb R)$ that contains $T_3(\mathbb R)$. However I am unsure if it is maximal.

I am not sure how to proceed for $T_n(\mathbb R)$ for $n\geq 4$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n \ge 2$ the set $$S = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & x^T \\ 0 & A \end{bmatrix} : a \in \mathbf{R}, x \in \mathbf{R}^{n-1}, A \in M_{n-1}(\mathbf{R}) \right\}$$ is a maximal subring of $M_n(\mathbf{R})$ containing the upper triangular matrices. To see this, suppose $S' \subseteq M_n(\mathbf{R})$ is a subring properly containing $S$. Then $S'$ contains a matrix of the form $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ v & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ where $v \in \mathbf{R}^{n-1}$ is nonzero. For each $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$ let $A_i \in M_n(\mathbf{R})$ be such that $A_i v = e_i$, where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th standard basis vector. Then
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & A_i \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ v & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ A_iv & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ e_i & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in S'.$$ From this it is easy to see that $M_n(\mathbf{R}) \subseteq S'$.